# Identify this grid placement/guessing game

Tags: identify-this-game

Please help me know the name of this game, i can't google it because i don't know what the proper keyword is.

Basically Its a board game played mostly by 2 or more depending on the creator of the board game.

The theme can be a Tank battle , or ship battle or anything.

You play the Game by placing your pieces, example tanks on a Grid of numbers and letters,

The objective of the game is to guess and destroy the pieces of your opponents are in the grid by guessing the Grid like A1, OR C3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like Battleship: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(game) You place your ships on the grid and you have to guess the positions of the opponent's ships.